# Devise ajax login/register with Rails remote: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Without `remote: true` in my form, the login works. But, when using `remote: true`, and attempting to login via ajax, I receive this error:

```
You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
```

The requests are both post. Can somebody enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some steps that you need to follow:

**1) Check whether the request made is of javascript.**

To verify that you should check the request header to see what the Accept parameter is. If it says `application/javascript` then it's all good. Use tools like firebug to check the request headers easily.

**2) What javascript files are included?**

Secondly, a very common problem when starting to try out the `:remote => true` is that the required **javascript libraries** are not included in your code. So my guess is that the following code is missing from your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

If that is the case, just include it inside the html header.

**3) Check the controller: does it have a respond_to block?**

If you generated your app with `rails generate scaffold`, it will have something like

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { .... }
    end
```

Replace the above code with:

```
respond_to :html, :js
```

**OR**

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.xml  { .... }
    end
```

**4) Setup CSRF Token in your application.js**

```
$(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
      var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
    }
  });
});
```

**5) Post your login information**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/users/sign_in.json',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {user: {email: 'email@example.com', password: 'password'}},
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //called when successful
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That has me slightly closer. I now receive the error **undefined method `to' for nil:NilClass**, **devise (2.1.2) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:129:in http_auth_header?**. This *all* works fine via html, but not ajax.

Comment: CSRF token is being sent with request. Login information is being sent correctly. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 all check out.

Comment: This seems to be the problem of your devise routing. Failure application(failure_app.rb) is called every time `:warden` is thrown from any strategy or hook. Responsible for redirect the user to the sign in page based on current scope and mapping. If no scope is given, redirect to the default_url.